# com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fatal-error

I had to enable MultiDex in my Android App, it appears to be working in all SDK except the ones related to 4.4 and 4.2 which unfortunately are the most popular Android versions for my app at the moment.

Here is the crash report in Play Dev Console

```
java.lang.VerifyError: com/google/android/gms/measurement/internal/zzw
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1058)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5022)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4607)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4547)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1400)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias 'XXXXX'
        keyPassword 'XXXXXX'
        storeFile file('C:/XXXXXXX')
        storePassword 'XXXXXXX'
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "net.digitalageservices.minecraftyourself"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 42
    versionName "4.7.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        shrinkResources true
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/apache-commons-httpmime.jar')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
//  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile files('libs/easyandroidanimationslibrary-v0.5.jar')
compile ('com.adincube.sdk:AdinCube-Java-3fff:1.+@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
}

repositories {
maven {
    url 'http://repository.adincube.com/maven'
}
}
```

Here is the Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="net.digitalageservices.minecraftyourself">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />


<!-- To access accounts configured on device -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- To use account credentials -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:name=".app.MyApplication">
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name="com.chartboost.sdk.CBImpressionActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

    <activity
        android:name=".LoginPage"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MineCraftActivit_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <!--<intent-filter>-->
            <!--<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />-->
            <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />-->
        <!--</intent-filter>-->
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".StartActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".AboutUsPage"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".ListImageActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".ViewPagerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
  <activity
        android:name=".NewsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

    <!--
     Optionally, register AnalyticsReceiver and AnalyticsService to support background
     dispatching on non-Google Play devices
   -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />

    <!--
         Optionally, register CampaignTrackingReceiver and CampaignTrackingService to enable
         installation campaign reporting
    -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />

    <activity android:name="com.purplebrain.adbuddiz.sdk.AdBuddizActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
</application>
```

I know I need to do something in the Manifest, Activity with extends or something, and Gradle, but everything I have tried is failing or only partially works. I just don't know where or how to properly fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Turn MultiDex off and read below :)

here is your problem:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

play services are very huge lib that contains tons of child libs remove this line and go and read [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project) and add ONLY libraries that you use. 99% guarantee will be no need to use MultiDex :)

for example if you use only maps then compile only:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
```